# LEAFLET Filter by icon name / title

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-maps-markers

I'm attempting to implement some example code which I have found online, however, I am struggling to do so. I want to be able to filter the markers with a leaflet control box by marker.options.title name similar to how this example shows
http://jsfiddle.net/RogerHN/31v2afte/2/
Due to my markers being pulled from an API I am struggling to implement the switch loop without it freezing up my browser as it doesn't stop looping the array. if anybody could point me in the right direction of implementation it would be greatly appreciated.

```
for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    switch (locations[i][2]) {            
        case 'A' : 
            markersA.push(L.marker([locations[i][3], locations[i][4]]));
            break;        
        case 'B' :
            markersB.push(L.marker([locations[i][3], locations[i][4]]));
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

I have attached below my current up to date working code without the implementation
https://jsfiddle.net/jgov83fg/21/

Comment: Which API? What is the timing of the requests? Are there race conditions? Are you cleaning up the `LayerGroup`s?

Comment: I'm trying to create multiple marker arrays which contain a specific category of crime using switch case but it's just not working. the API is Police.uk crime database api.

Comment: Add those calls to your code snippet, please. Nobody can guess how the data looks like (how many entries? are there circular references?) without actually having a look at it.

Comment: How much data are you pulling back in the request to the API?  You mention you have an endless for loop.  I don't see how that could happen with the above code.  Have you added a `console.log(locations.length);` to see how much data you're pulling in?

Comment: With the above code isn't implemented in my working example I removed it as i figured it was no use. would it be best to reimplement it and update the thread, when I was trying to push the marker I and log the marker group in the console nothing would appear.

Comment: I suggest you take a step back, think what the problem really is, how others can see that same problem happening, and then [make a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)